# How can I cancel a Huawei system update?

Tags: ota-update, huawei, device-firmware

This morning I turned I my Huawei Mediapad M8 and it tried to do a system update, although I don't remember seeing a notice about one. However it fails with the error "The update package does not exist. Please download the package again."

The only option available is to reboot the system, I cannot even turn it off.

The correct method to reach the android recovery menu I  this device seems to be different depending on which website I look at, but I tried them all and I always end up with the same screen.

Is there any way to escape from this wretched update that I never wanted in the first place, apart from to somehow flash the device through an external data connection?